# ¿Cómo hacer read-only y editable la fila de una tabla al hacer click en un boton con Angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript, table, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla con campos que contienen diferentes elementos, un mat select, mat datepicker y un mat input los cuales hacen editable a la tabla, también tengo el boton **guardar**, que se encarga de recoger el valor de cada uno de los campos.

Lo que necesito es que cuando entres a la pagina, la tabla se muestre como read only nada más y que cuando des click en el boton  de **guardar** , se habilite la edición de los elementos que conforman la fila , es posible hacer eso?

lo que busco es que el guardado se haga únicamente por fila, ya que así como lo tengo ahorita si editas un campo de la fila 1 y das click en el boton guardar de la fila 3 lo hace

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      
        <mat-select
          [(value)]="element.cveEstado"
          (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel"
            [value]="estatus.cveEstado"
            [ngClass]="{
              'text-red': estatus.cveEstado == 'ERR',
              'text-blue': estatus.cveEstado == 'INP'
            }"
          >
            {{ estatus.descripcion }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
     
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          [value]="element.comentario"
          (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.horaInicio }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="picker"
          [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
          (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
          matIconSuffix
          [for]="picker"
        ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
      <button mat-button (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'botonSave'
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);


    
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
     this.comentIngresado = e.value;
     console.log(' INPUT  ' +this.comentIngresado);

  }


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  '  + this.fechaIngresada);
  }


  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }



  guardar() {
    if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
      alert('No se han modificado campos');
    } else {
      

      this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
      this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
      this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
      this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
        this.fechaIngresada
      );
      this.controlService.updateCampos(this.controlModel).subscribe((data) => {
        this.controlModel = data;
        this.comentIngresado = '';
        this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
        this.fechaIngresada = '';

        alert('Agregado correctamente');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega `[disabled]="!element.editar"` a cada fila, mientras que en el botón para guardar solamente mandas la fila `guardar(row)`, seria igual si quieres eliminar.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

**Componente**

```
  guardar(row: any) {
    if (row.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${row.nombre}`);
      row.editar = false;
      // Agregas llamada al servicio para que se guarde al dejar de editar
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${row.nombre}`);
      row.editar = true;
    }
  }
  eliminar(row: any) {
    const index = this.dataSource.data.indexOf(row);
    this.dataSource.data.splice(index);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource.data);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Fecha">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="row.fecha">
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="picker"
          [value]="row.fecha"
          [disabled]="!row.editar"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Acciones">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Acciones</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="guardar(row)">
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="eliminar(row)">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Icon | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview)

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré